# Can you load jQuery contextMenu with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I want to load a jQuery plugin [jQuery contextMenu](http://swisnl.github.io/jQuery-contextMenu/) with JavaScript.

I tried following JavaScript script on Chrome developer tool console and receive an error `VM4631:1 Uncaught TypeError: $.contextMenu is not a function`.

```
// setting up jQuery contextMenu Plugin 

function dynamicallyLoadScript(url) {
    var script = document.createElement("script");
    script.src = url;
    document.head.appendChild(script);
}

dynamicallyLoadScript('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js')

var link = document.createElement( "link" );
link.href = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-contextmenu/2.7.0/jquery.contextMenu.min.css" ;
link.type = "text/css";
link.rel = "stylesheet";
link.media = "screen,print";
document.getElementsByTagName( "head" )[0].appendChild( link );

dynamicallyLoadScript('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-contextmenu/2.7.0/jquery.contextMenu.min.js')
dynamicallyLoadScript('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-contextmenu/2.7.0/jquery.ui.position.js')

// testing 

$.contextMenu({
    selector: '#post-868 > div > header > h2 > a',
    items: {
        copy: {
            name: "Copy",
            callback: function(key, opt){
                alert("Clicked on " + key);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short answer**

The problem is that `<script>`s loading is an asynchronous operation.
And because you are dynamically inserting these scripts, when your `$.contextMenu` instruction is executed, the necessary scripts are not loaded yet.

**Explanations**

When you **statically** define multiple scripts using `<script>` tags in the page `<head>`, the browser will fetch them in parrallel and execute them as soon as possible, **maintaining their order** (and blocking further parsing of the page).

But in your case, you are **dynamically** inserting `<script>` tags one by one into the page `<head>`, which means that:

- The order of these scripts execution is unknown (as soon as it is fetched, it is executed)
- Execution continue while your `<script>`s are loading, so `$.contextMenu` is executed before your `<script>`s are indeed loaded.

To illustrate this, I have added a `console.log` just before the `$.contextMenu` instruction and added a `console.time/timeEnd` in the `dynamicallyLoadScript` function:

```js
function dynamicallyLoadScript(url) {
    var script = document.createElement("script");
    script.src = url;
    // Print log on script loaded
 script.onload = () => { console.timeEnd(url); };
    console.time(url);
    document.head.appendChild(script);
}

dynamicallyLoadScript('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js')

var link = document.createElement( "link" );
link.href = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-contextmenu/2.7.0/jquery.contextMenu.min.css" ;
link.type = "text/css";
link.rel = "stylesheet";
link.media = "screen,print";
document.getElementsByTagName( "head" )[0].appendChild( link );

dynamicallyLoadScript('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-contextmenu/2.7.0/jquery.contextMenu.min.js')
dynamicallyLoadScript('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-contextmenu/2.7.0/jquery.ui.position.js')

console.log('Calling $.contextMenu');

$.contextMenu({
    selector: '#post-868 > div > header > h2 > a',
    items: {
        copy: {
            name: "Copy",
            callback: function(key, opt){
                alert("Clicked on " + key);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

I don't know why you are loading your scripts this way.
If you add `script.async = false;`, your scripts will be loaded in the right order but this will not prevent `$.contextMenu` to be executed first.
I would suggest you to have a look at [this great HTML5 Rocks article](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/script-loading/) dealing with script loading.